# What is wrong with my declaration of member template function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare a member function outside of the template - GetValue.

I'm getting error: 
main.cpp|16|error: redefinition of 'GenericType Test::GetValue()'|
|error: 'GenericType Test::GetValue()' previously declared here|

```
#include <iostream>

template <class GenericType>
class Test {
public:
        GenericType x;
        Test(){        }

        Test(int y) : x(  y){ }

        GenericType GetValue(){}
};


template <class GenericType>
GenericType Test<GenericType>::GetValue(){
    return x;

}

int main()
{

    Test<int> y(5);
    std::cout << y.GetValue();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the member function *definition*

```
GenericType GetValue(){}
```

to a member function *declaration*

```
GenericType GetValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your class declaration you already define the `GetValue()` method.

Just do:

```
template <class GenericType>
class Test {
public:
     // ...

     GenericType GetValue();
     //                    ^
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well you are defining at 2 points the function in your code:

```
template <class GenericType>
class Test {
public:
        GenericType x;
        Test(){        }

        Test(int y) : x(  y){ }

        GenericType GetValue(){} //<--here
};


template <class GenericType>
GenericType Test<GenericType>::GetValue(){ // <- and Here!
    return x;

}

int main()
{

    Test<int> y(5);
    std::cout << y.GetValue();
    return 0;
}
```

the first definition should be a declaration, change the {} for a ;

```
GenericType GetValue();
```

Now you are saying that this function will be defined later in the code

Answer (score 1):

```
GenericType GetValue(){}
```

This is not a declaration, this is a declaration and definition.

```
GenericType GetValue();
```

This is a declaration.

More, you should add const wherever possible. Like this:

```
GenericType GetValue() const { return x; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on const. I forgot to add it. Good rmeinder for me.